# Access stored procedure value with LINQ. Entity Framework 5, DB first

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is working correctly. However, I am not able to retrieve it.

My current function to retrieve the value from the stored procedure is:

```
    public static int GetCsStatus()
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter s = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Status", typeof(int));
            int r = db.proc_CsStatus(120, s);//.ToString());
            return r;
        }
    }
```

I don't mind if this is changed or not used at all. I am currently getting a "r" value of -1 when I am expecting a 0 or 1.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
    USE [DATABASE_CS]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CsStatus]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @TimeLimit Int,
        @Status Int OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        -- Declare variables.
        DECLARE @LastUpdate Int

        -- Calculate the LastUpdate.
        SELECT @LastUpdate = DATEDIFF(second, Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        FROM Heartbeat
        WHERE Id=1

        -- Compare it to the TimeLimit.
        IF @LastUpdate > @TimeLimit SELECT @Status = 0
        ELSE SELECT @Status = 1
    END
    GO
```

Any input is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After executing your procedure, your the `ObjectParameter s` will contain the value.  Your procedure call will not return it.  The value you are looking for should be able to be found in `s.Value`.

Try the following:

```
public static int GetCsStatus()
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter s = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Status", typeof(int));
        int r = db.proc_CsStatus(120, s);
        return (int)s.Value;
    }
}
```

The value which you are returning(`r`) is the number of rows affected by your procedure.

**More Info:**

Behind the scenes, your procedure is doing something along the lines of the following:

```
return base.ExecuteFunction("proc_CsStatus", input, output);
```

`ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction()` returns the number of rows affected by the call.

Comment: I get a red swiggly that says "Error 2 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you probably could just `return s`, not `s.Value`

Comment: S gives me this error "Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 'int' =/

Comment: Your two statements contridict each other.  You say `s` is an `int` above in your first error, then you say its an `ObjectParameter` in the latter.  If it is an `ObjectParameter`, you should be able to use `s.Value`, because `ObjectParameter` has a property of `Value`.

Comment: If I had to guess.  I'd assume you tried to return `r.Value` the first time.

Comment: @JefferyKhan sorry but I'm just reading you what Visual Studios displays to me =[ i wish one of the moethods worked

Comment: Would it matter if this function is under a public static class

Comment: I just reproduced your environment.  The only change I had to make, was that I needed to cast `s.Value` as an `int`.  I have edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: @JefferyKhan you sir are too smart